# Present perfect tense in if clause

Tags: tense

Regarding the present perfect tense: suppose my friend and I have made a plan today that we are going to go shopping today before evening, but at the moment we are still in the office and I am telling to my friend, *If we have finished our job by 3 o'clock, then we can go shopping.*

Is this sentence OK? Can this be said like this in English or there are other ways to express the same thing?

Comment: Idiomatically, most speakers would probably use Simple Past (*If we finished*, without ***have***). And because it's a hypothetical situation, *...then we **could** go shopping* might be preferred. But note that it's also perfectly okay to use the "Present in the Future" version *If we **finish** by 3 o'clock...* Personally I think that latter version more strongly implies that the speaker is *urging* the addressee to agree that finishing before 3 is a good idea, so both parties will share common purpose in trying to bring that situation about.

Comment: You don't need the perfect; "If we finish our job by 3 o'clock, then we can go shopping" is fine.

Comment: What is hypothetical situation

Comment: you might find actual examples like "if we finished by 3, then..." but this is decidedly non-standard. I would only use this for the past, e.g. "if they finished by 3 yesterday,  then you can pay them for their work."  for future uncertain situations only "if we have finished by 3" or "if we finish by 3" are idiomatically correct.

Comment: a hypothetical situation is just a possible situation.  since you are talking about the future when you say "if X  by 3 o'clock then Y" (where 3 o'clock refers to the future, not the past), the event X may or may not actually occur, which makes it hypothetical,  in a sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sentence is grammatically correct. Usually it's written as "*3 o'clock*" though.

Another way to write this sentence would be, "*If we have finished work by 3 o'clock, then we can go shopping*."

Or, to mix things around, "*We can go shopping if we finish work by 3 o'clock*."